# How to stop propagation when click to custom button in kendo ui grid header

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid. I use headerTemplate to add custom button to column header.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  sortable: true,
  columns: [
      {
          field: 'test',
          title: 'My test',
          headerTemplate: '<span class="column-edit fa fa-pencil"></span>'
      },
      {
          field: 'my_column',
          title: 'My column'
      }
  ],
  dataSource: [
      {test: '3', my_column: 4}, 
      {test: '4', my_column: 4}, 
      {test: '6', my_column: 2}, 
      {test: '7', my_column: 1}, 
      {test: '7', my_column: 9}
  ]
});
$(document).on('click', '.column-edit', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('edit');
});
```

[This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anhnt/UtcQa/)

My question is: How to prevent sort trigger when user click to pencil icon? My code didn't work as expected.

Many thanks,

Anh Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off) on your `anchor tag` like,

```
$('.column-edit').closest('a').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('edit');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/UtcQa/4/)

Comment: Thanks, but that seems do disable the sorting feature

Comment: Remove the `off()` and try

Comment: I think your code will bind an event to anchor instead. My expectation is preventing anchor trigger when click to pencil.

Comment: In my case, columns are added dynamically, then your code will not work. thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.column-edit').closest('a').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    alert('edit');
    return false
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Click Your Header Without Sort**

I encountered the same problem. It seems that the grid wasn't ready. I tried using (closest('a')) but that didn't help. I added a textbox so the following code was successful:

```
function gridDataBound() {
    fadeInContent();
    setTimeout(function () {
       // Prevent sort when filter is clicked.
       $("input.search-filter").on('click', function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   }, 200);
}
```

The timeout worked for me at 80. But below that the grid hadn't filled with data yet. I could probably make it by 300 ms but after that I think users would be frequently clicking too early.

It is probably better to add the handler at dynamic control creation time.